# How to differentiate imaginary vector?

Tags: partial-derivative, mean-square-error

I am finding a vector $\mathbf{c}$ that minimizes $J(\mathbf{c})$, that is
$J(\mathbf{c}) = \text{E}\left\{\left\vert\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r} -
 a_{t}\right\vert^2\right\}$.

$\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are both vector and $a_t$ is some scalar value.

---

My professor taught us:

We need to find $\mathbf{c}$ such that
$$\frac{\partial J(\mathbf{c}) }{ \partial \mathbf{c}^H} = \text{E}\left\{ 
\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} - a_t^*) \right\} = 0$$

---

I agree with the direction of solving the above; since $f(t)=\vert t \vert^2$  is convex, it is enough to find the point such that $df(t)/dt=0$.

---

However, I do not understand how
$$
\frac{\partial   \left\vert\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r} - a_{t}\right\vert^2   }{ \partial \mathbf{c}^H} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{c}^H}\left[ (\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r}-a_t)(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c}-a_t^*)\right]
$$
becomes
$$
\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} - a_t^*) 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85648/why-can-the-complex-conjugate-of-a-variable-be-treated-as-a-constant-when-differ) to see why 
$
\frac{\partial \bar{z}}{\partial z} = 0
$,
which we will use shortly.

Define:
$$
\mathbf{v} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{c}^H} \left\vert \mathbf{c}^H \mathbf{r} - a_t\right\vert^2 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{c}^H}
\left[ (\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r} - a_t)(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} -a_t^*) \right]
$$
where $\mathbf{c},\mathbf{r}$ are vectors and $a_t$ is a scalar.

For simplicity, just consider the $i$th component:
\begin{align}
v_i 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial c^*_i}
\left[ (\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r} - a_t)(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} -a_t^*) \right] \\
&= (\mathbf{c}^H\mathbf{r} - a_t) r_i^* \underbrace{\frac{\partial c_i}{\partial c_i^*}}_{0}
+
(\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} - a_t^*)r_i \\
&= (\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} -a_t^*)r_i
\end{align}

Since each component looks like that, the full vector can be written:
$$
\mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{r}^H\mathbf{c} -a_t^*)\mathbf{r}
$$
Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Really nice impressed answer!!! Thank you so much. component-wise differentiation is very understandable. However, I need to memorize $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^*}=0$ for now. Imaginary calculus is so difficult for me, not a mathematician but an engineer.

Comment: @Danny_Kim Glad to help :)