# What is the meaning of the derivative of the real and complex part ($\text{Re}'$, $\text{Im}'$)?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, real-numbers

Given a complex valued function $z(t) = a\exp((b+i \omega)t)$, with $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $b, \omega, t \in \mathbb{R}$, what is the meaning of $\text{Re}'(z(t))$ and $\text{Im}'(z(t))$ in the partial derivatives
$$\frac{d}{da}\text{Re}(z(t)) = \text{Re}'(z(t))\frac{d}{da}z(t)$$
$$\frac{d}{da}\text{Im}(z(t)) = \text{Im}'(z(t))\frac{d}{da}z(t)$$
after applying the chain rule?

I have difficulties to understand what $\text{Re}'$ and $\text{Im}'$ means conceptually, since I understand $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ as helper functions to extract the real and imaginary part respectively and thus I don't understand how I can analytically calculate their derivatives?

Comment: Firstly, be aware of what $\text{Re} \circ z$ is a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $t \mapsto z(t) \mapsto \text{Re}(z(t))$.

Answer (score 1):

Treat $a,\,a^\ast$ as independent variables so$$\operatorname{Re}a=\frac{a+a^\ast}{2},\,\operatorname{Im}a=\frac{a-a^\ast}{2i}\implies\partial_a=\frac12\partial_{\operatorname{Re}a}+\frac{1}{2i}\partial_{\operatorname{Im}a}.$$Since $\operatorname{Re}z=e^{bt}(\operatorname{Re}a\cdot\cos\omega t-\operatorname{Im}a\cdot\sin\omega t)$, $$\partial_a\operatorname{Re}z=\frac12 e^{bt}\cos\omega t-\frac{1}{2i}e^{bt}\sin\omega t=\frac12 e^{(b+i\omega)t}.$$Dividing out $dz/da=e^{(b+i\omega)t}$, the first equation requires $$\operatorname{Re}^\prime(z)=\frac12,$$which makes sense because $\operatorname{Re}z=\frac{z+z^\ast}{2}$. Similarly, you can show $\partial_a\operatorname{Im}z=\frac{1}{2i}e^{(b+i\omega)t}$, whence$$\operatorname{Im}^\prime z=\frac{1}{2i},$$which makes sense because $\operatorname{Im}z=\frac{z-z^\ast}{2i}$.

Comment: Thank you! The trick of writing $\text{Re}$ and $\text{Im}$ explicitly is great. However, I think there is a few mistakes: $\frac{d}{da} \text{Re}(z(t)) = \frac{z(t)+z^*(t)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{d}{da} z(t) + \frac{d}{da} z^*(t)) = \frac{1}{2}(\exp(bt)(\cos(t\omega)+i\sin(t\omega))+\exp(bt)(\cos(t\omega)-i\sin(t\omega))) = \exp(bt)cos(t\omega) = \text{Re}(\frac{d}{da} z(t))$ and accordingly $\frac{d}{da} \text{Im}(z(t)) = -i\text{Im}(\frac{d}{da} z(t))$

Comment: @Genius $\frac{d}{da}\left(z^\ast\right)\ne\left(\frac{dz}{da}\right)^\ast$ in general because $a$ is complex viz. $\frac{da^\ast}{da}=0$. For example, with $z=a$ this inequality becomes $\frac{d0}{da}\ne1^\ast$.

Comment: According to what I have found out by now, $a$ and $a*$ can not be treated as independent variables, one has to follow the Cauchy-Riemann equations instead to find the solution

Comment: @Genius [You read wrong, then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85648/why-can-the-complex-conjugate-of-a-variable-be-treated-as-a-constant-when-differ). See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives).

Comment: Posted my solution. Let me know what you think. For the gradient approach I am implementing, my solution actually works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be found by using the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

\begin{align*}
Re'(z(t)) &= \frac{\partial\text{Re}(\text{Re}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Re}(a)} + i\frac{\partial\text{Im}(\text{Re}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Re}(a)}\\
&= \frac{\partial\text{Im}(\text{Re}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Im}(a)} + i\frac{\partial\text{Re}(\text{Re}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Im}(a)}\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Im'(z(t)) &= \frac{\partial\text{Re}(\text{Im}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Re}(a)} + i\frac{\partial\text{Im}(\text{Im}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Re}(a)}\\
&= \frac{\partial\text{Im}(\text{Im}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Im}(a)} + i\frac{\partial\text{Re}(\text{Im}(z(t)))}{\partial\text{Im}(a)}\\
\end{align*}

Where the real part of $z(t)$ is $$\text{Re}(z(t)) = \text{Re}(a)\exp(bt)\cos(\omega t) - \text{Im}(a)\exp(bt)\sin(\omega t)$$ and the imaginary part of $z(t)$ is $$\text{Im}(z(t)) = \text{Re}(a)\exp(bt)\sin(\omega t) + \text{Im}(a)\exp(bt)\cos(\omega t)$$

and therefore $$Re'(z(t)) = \exp(bt)\cos(\omega t)$$ and $$Im'(z(t)) = \exp(bt)\sin(\omega t)\text{.}$$

For the whole solution, we have to apply the chain rule, which then finally yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}Re(z(t)) &= \exp(bt)\cos(\omega t)\exp((b+i\omega)t)\\
&= \exp((2b+i\omega)t)\cos(\omega t)
\end{align*} and 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}Im(z(t)) &= \exp(bt)\sin(\omega t)\exp((b+i\omega)t)\\
&= \exp((2b+i\omega)t)\sin(\omega t)\text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: You might want to double-check how often $b$ appears in your final results. Your Cauchy-Riemann equations can be simplified with results such as $$\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Re}w=\operatorname{Re}w,\,\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{Im}w=\operatorname{Im}w,\,\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Im}w=\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{Re}w=0.$$

Comment: @J.G. Why are our solutions different? What is the correct solution and why?

Comment: You seem to be differentiating with respect to $a$ rather than $z$. The equations you asked about in the original question were clearly doing the latter.